# get xml response from webservice in php

Tags: php, xml, web-services

i'm trying to make a little webservice that returns an xml file that i retrieve with php file_put_contents method. but it doesn't work. i don't know where i'm doing wrong. Thanks for your help. i'm a newbie!

here is the webservice

```
<?php

include('confi.php');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
//get data
$artist = isset($_POST['artist']) ? $_POST['artist'] : "";
$title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "";
$dateplayed = isset($_POST['date_played']) ? $_POST['date_played'] : "";

//insert data into database
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `tuto_db`.`songs` (`ID`, `artist`, `title`, "
        . "`dateplayed`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);");

$stmt->bind_param(NULL, $artist, $title, $dateplayed);

$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

$array = array(
    "artist" => $artist,
    "title" => $title,
    "date_played" => $dateplayed
);

//creating object of simpleXmlElement
$xml_song_info = new SimpleXMLElement("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><song_info></user_info>");

//function call to convert array to xml
array_to_xml($array, $xml_song_info);

$xml_file = $xml_song_info->asXML('song.xml');

//i've tried to output these variables instead of: return $xml_file;
//but i get no result
echo $xml_song_info->asXML('song.xml');

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . " : " . $value;
}

return $xml_file;
}

//function defination to convert array to xml
function array_to_xml($array, &$xml_song_info) {
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        if (!is_numeric(($key))) {
            $subnode = $xml_song_info->addChild("$key");
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        } else {
            $subnode = $xml_song_info->addChild("item$key");
            array_to_xml($value, $subnode);
        }
    } else {
        $xml_song_info->addChild("$key", htmlspecialchars("$value"));
    }
}
}
```

here are the requests

```
private $webService = 'http://localhost/wsTuto/ws_sendSongsToDb.php';

public function sendHttpPostRequest($data) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->content .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    $this->curl = curl_init($this->webService);

    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->content);

    $this->response = curl_exec($this->curl);

    $status = curl_getinfo($this->curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
}

public function getMessage($url){
    $this->curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($this->curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($this->curl);

    curl_close($this->curl);
    return $data;
}

$this->sendHttpPostRequest($this->array);
        file_put_contents($this->path . '/song.xml', $this->getMessage(
        $this->webService));
```

this is the code that i get in the file

```
Connected successfully
```

confi.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


try{
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=tuto_db", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully";
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
echo "Connexion failes: " . $ex->getMessage();
```

Comment: Did you notice the error message in that code? Crucial.

Comment: now i notice, i didn't pay attention cause the data is sent to the database anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML you're getting back is actually the PHP error message.
It's got the complete call stack in there.

Based on what it says, you want to stop using the `mysql_connect()` method (File `C:\wamp64\www\wsTuto\confi.php`) and use something like PDO and Parameterised queries instead.

I can see you're using `mysql_real_escape_string`, but It's worth taking the time to read a PDO tutorial and try using prepared statements. Have a look at [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: i've changed to PDO, updated the message in the file. still don't have the xml!

Comment: I'm a little confused as to whether or not you own the web service - the `C:\wamp64\www\wsTuto\confi.php` file - is that yours? If it is, there's still a `mysql_connect()` statement somewhere in there that is causing PHP to crash (and subsequently fail to return the XML)

Comment: i've added the confi.php file and updated the code  with prepared statement. still the same message in the file!!

Comment: OK. Good that there's no error now, but from what I can see, your main web service isn't actually outputting anything (which would be why you're getting a blank file). You have `$xml_file = $xml_song_info->asXML('song.xml');`, which means you're writing to a filesystem. If I understand correctly, you need something that echoes the file.

Maybe try `echo $xml_song_info->asXML();` and see if the XML gets echoed.

Comment: thanks, but the `echo $xml_song_info->asXML();` doesn't output anything. i've tried to output the arrray instead of the xml in case  xml file was faulty, but i still get the same output in the file "`Connected successfully`." i'm wondering if the mistake is not in the `getMessage($url)` method, cause the request to the web service is working, because the data is sent to database, but the response from the web service is not outputting anything else than the success of the connexion! thanks again

Comment: It *sounds* like the database query is causing the application to crash. At this point, I'd be adding breakpoints throughout your code to see where things are going wrong. I think it may be terminating early. Put in some `echo __FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__ . "\n";` statements to help find out where your code actually gets to. Also `print_r` some of your variables to make sure they have data in them when expected. More than likely, it's going to be some function causing a crash.

Comment: i can get a response with the echo now. it was some function causing a crash. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

the code that works:

The webservice

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
//get data
$artist = isset($_POST['artist']) ? $_POST['artist'] : "";
$title = isset($_POST['title']) ? $_POST['title'] : "";
$dateplayed = isset($_POST['date_played']) ? $_POST['date_played'] : "";

//insert data into database
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `tuto_db`.`songs` (`artist`, `title`, "
        . "`dateplayed`) VALUES ('" . $_POST['artist'] . "','" . $_POST['title'] .
        "','" . $_POST['date_played'] . "')");

$stmt->bindParam(1, $artist);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $title);
$stmt->bindParam(3, $dateplayed);

$sent = false;

if($stmt->execute()){
    $sent = true;
}

echo "New records created successfully";

$conn = NULL;

$xmlstr = <<<XML
<songinfo>
    <sent>$sent</sent>
    <title>$title</title>
    <artist>$artist</artist>           
</songinfo>
XML;

//creating object of simpleXmlElement
$xml_song_info = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

//output the xml
echo $xml_song_info->asXML();
```

the request to get the xml response

```
public function sendHttpRequest($data) {

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        $this->content .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
    }

    $context_options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
            . "Content-length: " . strlen($this->content) . "\r\n",
            'content' => $this->content 
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($context_options);

    $this->response = file_get_contents($this->webService, false, $context);

    $fp = fopen($this->path . '/song.xml', 'ab');

    fwrite($fp, $this->response);


}
```